# How to cancel a wasm process from within a webworker

Tags: javascript, c++, web-worker, emscripten, webassembly

I have a wasm process (compiled from c++) that processes data inside a web application. Let's say the necessary code looks like this:

```
std::vector<JSONObject> data
for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
{
    process_data(data[i]);

    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
        bool is_cancelled = check_if_cancelled();
        if (is_cancelled) {
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

This code basically "runs/processes a query" similar to a SQL query interface:

[image]

However, queries may take several minutes to run/process and at any given time the user may cancel their query. The cancellation process would occur in the normal javascript/web application, outside of the service Worker running the wasm.

My question then is what would be an example of how we could know that the user has clicked the 'cancel' button and communicate it to the wasm process so that knows the process has been cancelled so it can exit? Using the `worker.terminate()` is not an option, as we need to keep all the loaded data for that `worker` and cannot just kill that worker (it needs to stay alive with its stored data, so another query can be run...).

What would be an example way to communicate here between the javascript and worker/wasm/c++ application so that we can know when to exit, and how to do it properly?

Additionally, let us suppose a typical query takes 60s to run and processes 500MB of data in-browser using cpp/wasm.

---

**Update:** I think there are the following possible solutions here based on some research (and the initial answers/comments below) with some feedback on them:

1. Use two workers, with one worker storing the data and another worker processing the data. In this way the processing-worker can be terminated, and the data will always remain. **Feasible?** Not really, as it would take way too much time to copy over ~ 500MB of data to the webworker whenever it starts. This could have been done (previously) using [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer), but its support is now quite limited/nonexistent due to some security concerns. Too bad, as this seems like by far the best solution if it were supported...
2. Use a single worker using [Emterpreter](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Emterpreter) and using `emscripten_sleep_with_yield`. **Feasible?** No, destroys performance when using Emterpreter (mentioned in the docs above), and slows down all queries by about 4-6x.
3. Always run a second worker and in the UI just display the most recent. **Feasible?** No, would probably run into quite a few OOM errors if it's not a shared data structure and the data size is 500MB x 2 = 1GB (500MB seems to be a large though acceptable size when running in a modern desktop browser/computer).
4. Use an API call to a server to store the status and check whether the query is cancelled or not. **Feasible?** Yes, though it seems quite heavy-handed to long-poll with network requests every second from every running query.
5. Use an incremental-parsing approach where only a row at a time is parsed. **Feasible?** Yes, but also would require a tremendous amount of re-writing the parsing functions so that every function supports this (the actual data parsing is handled in several functions -- filter, search, calculate,  group by, sort, etc. etc.
6. Use IndexedDB and store the state in javascript. Allocate a chunk of memory in WASM, then return its pointer to JavaScript. Then read database there and fill the pointer. Then process your data in C++. **Feasible?** Not sure, though this seems like the best solution if it can be implemented.
7. [Anything else?]

In the bounty then I was wondering three things:

1. If the above six analyses seem generally valid?
2. Are there other (perhaps better) approaches I'm missing?
3. Would anyone be able to show a very basic example of doing #6 -- seems like that would be the best solution if it's possible and works cross-browser.

Comment: "Using the worker.terminate() is not an option, as we need to keep all the loaded data for that worker and cannot just kill that worker" - could you create two workers? One which holds this data that needs to 'keep alive' and the other which performance the query processing which you can optionally terminate?

Comment: @ColinE -- yes of course! Or a shared worker. However the data is quite large (500MB), is there any overhead in transferring the data from one worker to another?

Comment: @ColinE by the way, I'm going to award a 300-500 point bounty for this question, so if you have a good answer that will solve the above (with zero performance overhead), please start posting!

Comment: are you using a javascript worker threads when calling your c++ code?

Comment: @Tomer -- yes we are.

Comment: If you can include more information / code on how you are calling the function from your main app and and from the worker I can update my answer below to be more specific

Comment: Have you had any luck?

Comment: @ColinE updated the question with more details. Thanks for the suggestion here.

Comment: I believe that #5 or #6 are both good approaches, however this is beyond my knowledge. If someone can come along and offer a good solution with the #6 approach I would say the bounty should go to them!

Comment: @david542 (I'm asking the obvious, but just to be sure), from a user experience perspective will it be a deal breaker if the cancel takes time (the time it takes to finish the query)? obviously this would be the easiest solution. In addition, you can do the following: when a user clicks on cancel and runs a new query, you can just queue it until the older query is done (and cancled). This should hide the user experience issue and will just make the next query take longer. Honestly, I think it should suffice.

Comment: @Tomer thanks for the question. The problem is queries can run forever. It's unfortunate, but users can do whatever they want and run things at their own risk with their data. Or, even with a "normal" pivot query, it could take a minute or so to complete. So having the user wait a minute (or have to close the tab if it becomes unresponsive) wouldn't really be a good solution.

Comment: @David542 Understood, then perhaps WASM (client side calculation) is not the best approach, and instead have it done on a server. #6 may be feasible, this will reduce the memory requirements in WASM, allowing you to execute multiple workers. But I guess it's up to you to decide how much effort it entitles and if it makes sense. When you do manage to solve it, let us know how. This is definitely IMHO an interesting use-case.

Comment: @Tomer -- I don't know about #6 (or other options) -- that's why I'm asking it here: I hope someone else does!

Comment: Me too! I’d love to see more on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Chrome (only) you may use shared memory (shared buffer as memory). And raise a flag in memory when you want to halt. Not a big fan of this solution (is complex and is supported only in chrome). It also depends on how your query works, and if there are places where the lengthy query can check the flag.

Instead you should probably call the c++ function multiple times (e.g. for each query) and check if you should halt after each call (just send a message to the worker to halt).

What I mean by multiple time is make the query in stages (multiple function cals for a single query). It may not be applicable in your case.

Regardless, AFAIK there is no way to send a signal to a Webassembly execution (e.g. Linux kill). Therefore, you'll have to wait for the operation to finish in order to complete the cancellation.

I'm attaching a code snippet that may explain this idea.

```html
worker.js:

... init webassembly

onmessage = function(q) {
 // query received from main thread.
 const result = ... call webassembly(q);
 postMessage(result);
}

main.js:

const worker = new Worker("worker.js");
const cancel = false;
const processing = false;

worker.onmessage(function(r) {
 // when worker has finished processing the query.
 // r is the results of the processing.
 processing = false;

 if (cancel === true) {
  // processing is done, but result is not required.
  // instead of showing the results, update that the query was canceled.
  cancel = false;
  ... update UI "cancled".
  return;
 }
 
 ... update UI "results r".
}

function onCancel() {
 // Occurs when user clicks on the cancel button.
 if (cancel) {
  // sanity test - prevent this in UI.
  throw "already cancelling";
 }
 
 cancel = true;
 
 ... update UI "canceling". 
}

function onQuery(q) {
 if (processing === true) {
  // sanity test - prevent this in UI.
  throw "already processing";
 }
 
 processing = true;
 // Send the query to the worker.
 // When the worker receives the message it will process the query via webassembly.
 worker.postMessage(q);
}
```

An idea from user experience perspective:
You may create ~two workers. This will take twice the memory, but will allow you to "cancel" "immediately" once. (it will just mean that in the backend the 2nd worker will run the next query, and when the 1st finishes the cancellation, cancellation will again become immediate).

Comment: how does "calling the c++ function multiple times" address the ability to cancel a query? And what exactly do you mean by "halt" a worker -- how would that be done in code?

Comment: Fair question. I'll see if I can find some time tomorrow to improve my answer with an example.

Comment: thanks for this updated response. I've updated the question here with more details.

Answer (score 2):

### Shared Thread

Since the worker and the C++ function that it called share the same thread, the worker will also be blocked until the C++ loop is finished, and won't be able to handle any incoming messages. I think the a solid option would minimize the amount of time that the thread is blocked by instead initializing one iteration at a time from the main application.

It would look something like this.

```
main.js  ->  worker.js  ->  C++ function  ->  worker.js  ->  main.js
```

### Breaking up the Loop

Below, C++ has a variable initialized at 0, which will be incremented at each loop iteration and stored in memory.
C++ function then performs one iteration of the loop, increments the variable to keep track of loop position, and immediately breaks.

```
int x;
x = 0; // initialized counter at 0

std::vector<JSONObject> data
for (size_t i = x; i < data.size(); i++)
{
    process_data(data[i]);

    x++ // increment counter
    break; // stop function until told to iterate again starting at x
}
```

Then you should be able to post a message to the web worker, which then sends a message to main.js that the thread is no longer blocked.

### Canceling the Operation

From this point, main.js knows that the web worker thread is no longer blocked, and can decide whether or not to tell the web worker to execute the C++ function again (with the C++ variable keeping track of the loop increment in memory.)

```
let continueOperation = true
// here you can set to false at any time since the thread is not blocked here

worker.expensiveThreadBlockingFunction()
// results in one iteration of the loop being iterated until message is received below

worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    if (continueOperation) {
        worker.expensiveThreadBlockingFunction()
        // execute worker function again, ultimately continuing the increment in C++
    } {
        return false
        // or send message to worker to reset C++ counter to prepare for next execution
    }
}
```

### Continuing the Operation

Assuming all is well, and the user has not cancelled the operation, the loop should continue until finished. Keep in mind you should also send a distinct message for whether the loop has completed, or needs to continue, so you don't keep blocking the worker thread.

Comment: thanks for this answer, this is great! I've updated the question with some feedback and some more information.